# Счётчик массива

Tags: c#

Имеется файл с 1000 строками, в строке разделитель запятая, во второй позиции хранятся числа:01,02,03,04,05,06.
Надо посчитать сколько было 01,02,03,04,05,06?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Создание папки и подпапок
            DirectoryInfo papka = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\a.filatov\Desktop\Test\");
            try
            {

                papka.CreateSubdirectory(@"Writer");
                papka.CreateSubdirectory(@"Incorrect");
            }
            catch (IOException e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }
            //Путь к файлу
            string path = @"C:\Users\a.filatov\Desktop\1\COMMA.txt";

            //Читаем текст в файле построчно
            string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);

            //Объявляем интервал времени
            TimeSpan intervaltimesum = new TimeSpan();

            //Текущее время в элементе массива
            TimeSpan current_time;

            //Счётчик
            int countTime = 0;

            //Создание потока для записи в файл
            StreamWriter W = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\a.filatov\Desktop\Test\Writer\Write.txt");
            StreamWriter A = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\a.filatov\Desktop\Test\Incorrect\Incorrect.txt");

            //Цикл для считывания строк
            for (int i = 19; i < 1019; i++)
            {
                //Установка разделителем массива запятой
                string[] elements = readText[i].Split(',');

                //Если четветрый элемент в строке существует, то работаем с ним
                if (elements.GetLength(0) > 4)
                {
                    //Разбор 4 элемента массива
                    try
                    {
                        //Разделитель ":"
                        string[] times = elements[4].Split(':');
                        int hours = int.Parse(times[0]);
                        int minutes = int.Parse(times[1]);
                        int seconds = int.Parse(times[2]);
                        current_time = TimeSpan.FromHours(hours) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);

                       // Запись в файл
                        W.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}  \t\t Текущее время = {3} Общее время = {4}", i - 18, elements[0], elements[4], current_time, intervaltimesum);

                        //Вывод 4 элемента массива в файл
                        if (current_time.TotalHours > 2)
                        {
                            // в отдельный файл выведем значение более 2-х часов
                            A.WriteLine("{0}", current_time);
                        }
                        else
                        {  // если меньше двух часов - тогда суммируем
                            intervaltimesum += current_time;
                            countTime++;
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        throw;
                    } 
                }

            }
            //Закрытие потока 
            A.Close();

            //Вывод среднего времени в нужном формате
            TimeSpan intervalAverage = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(intervaltimesum.TotalSeconds / countTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Среднее время = {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", intervalAverage);

            //Запись в файл времени 
            W.WriteLine("\n\n Всё время отклонения = {0} в секундах = {1}", intervaltimesum, intervaltimesum.TotalSeconds);

            //Запись среднего времени
             W.WriteLine(" Среднее время {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", intervalAverage);
            W.Close();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понял. Что за вторая позиция и что надо посчитать? И чем эти позиции разделены?

Comment: StackOverflow - это сообщество, где программисты **помогают** друг другу, а не просто решают чужие задачи от нечего делать. Если хотите помощи, то потрудитесь объяснить, что Вы уже сделали и в чем возникли проблемы.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что работа за автора

Comment: Я уже сделал Split запятой,прочитал построчно 1000 строк в текстовом файле, записал их в массив,задача в другом, всего 9 позиций в строке, 2 позиция строки содержит или 01, или 02, или 03, или 04, или 05,или 06, надо посчитать сколько было : 01,02,03,04,05,06? Новичок в C# не понимаю что надо применять?

Comment: Вы хотите посчитать количество повторяющихся "значений" в файле? т.е. 01 кол-во 5, 02 - 10 ну и т.п.. Я правильно понял?!

Comment: @Алекс если вы пытались решить задачу самостоятельно - приведите код в вопросе.

Comment: Да посчитать сколько в файле во второй позиции 01,02,03,04,05,06?

Comment: А PashPash фома неверующий?

Comment: @Алекс в приведённом вами коде не видно попыток решить поставленную задачу.

Comment: @Алекс нет, просто вопросы "помогите решить" без кода в них тут сжигают очень быстро :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть разные способы это сделать, в зависимости от ваших знаний и умений.

Для примера, вот три варианта.

1. Создать промежуточный массив и сравнивая полученное значение строки, суммировать соответствующую ячейку.

   ```
   String[] readText = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt");

   Int32[] arrCounter = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
   foreach (String text in readText) 
   {
       switch (text.Split(',')[1]) 
       {
           case "01": arrCounter[0]++; break;
           case "02": arrCounter[1]++; break;
           case "03": arrCounter[2]++; break;
           case "04": arrCounter[3]++; break;
           case "05": arrCounter[4]++; break;
           case "06": arrCounter[5]++; break;
       }
   }
   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("01: {0}; 02: {1}; 03: {2}; 04: {3}; 05: {4}; 06: {5}", 
   arrCounter[0], arrCounter[1], arrCounter[2], arrCounter[3], arrCounter[4], arrCounter[5]));
   ```

Минус данного подхода в том, что если значений много, ваш код очень быстро распухнет и его сложно будет поддерживать. Так же, он не сможет вам помочь, если вы заранее не знаете, какие могут быть значения в файле.

2. Использовать специальную динамическую коллекцию и заполнять ее, в данном случае Dictionary.

   ```
   Dictionary<String, Int32> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
   (String text in readText)
   {
       String val = text.Split(',')[1];
       if (dict.ContainsKey(val)) dict[val]++; 
           else dict.Add(val, 1);
   }
   foreach (String key in dict.Keys) 
       Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} : {1}", key, dict[key]));
   ```
3. Воспользоваться Linq, как в примере Bald56rus, что значительно сокращает код.

   ```
   var pre = readText.Select(p => new { Value = p.Split(',')[1] })
                     .GroupBy(p => p.Value)
                     .Select(p => new { Key = p.Key, Count = p.Count() });
   foreach (var p in pre) Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} : {1}", p.Key, p.Count));
   ```

Comment: Третий способ выдал ошибку

Comment: Не довадилось не один использовать(

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста третий способ подробнее

Comment: @Алекс, как я сказал, выбранный способ зависит от ваших знаний. Третий способ, это отдельная технология с C# которая носит название Linq(интегрированный язык запросов) и занимает отдельную главу на пару десятков страниц в книгах. При всем желании, я не смогу уместить весь этот объем в рамки ответа) Продолжайте учится и когда-нибудь вы до этого дойдете и прочитаете сами, а пока воспользуйтесь другим способом

Comment: Расскажите тогда о первом метеоде

Comment: Простой массив, где каждая позиция соответствует значению в файле. Нулевая - "01", первая - "02" и т.д., а значение в позиции означает сколько раз оно встретилось. Изначально выставляются нули. Далее просто проходимся по файлу и смотрим, какое там число в строке(switch или if) и увеличиваем соответствующую позицию массива на единицу. Это самый простой метод в лоб. -- А для второго способа читайте и коллекциях в C# и как они работают, тоже обширная тема.

Comment: Опробовал первым методом ругается

Comment: @Алекс, код проверен и протестирован перед тем, как был дан ответ. Тогда описывайте свой вариант кода, которым вы это пытались сделать, приведите какую ошибку и где выдает, на что ругается. Проще сделать это, задав новый вопрос.

Comment: Пишет что индекс находится вне границ массива.

Comment: @Алекс, нужно не только описание ошибки, но и ваш вариант кода. В данном участке ошибок нет, просто Вы видимо что-то не так делаете. Ну а узнать это можно только посмотрев, что Вы там конкретно сделали.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary<string, int> result = new Dictionary<string,int>();
//Считываем файл в массив строк
// если обрабатыватывать надо не все, то можеть считать файл сами
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("PathToFiles");

// данная строка означает следующее:
// каждую строку разбиваем на массив подстрок, разделитель запятая,
// берем 2 элемент массива(отсчет ведется с 0), делаем группировку
// по полученному значение и заносим это в новый анонимный тип
var pre = lines
    .Select(x => new { Value = x.Split(new char[] { ',' })[1] })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Value);

//здесь в результирующий словарь заносим необходимую информацию
в следующем  формате: Ключ 01, Количество 5, и т.п.
foreach (var p in pre)
{
    result.Add(p.Key, p.Count());
}
```

P.S. Код не тестировал.

Answer (score -3):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Создание папки и подпапок
            DirectoryInfo papka = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\a.filatov\Desktop\Test\");
            try
            {

                papka.CreateSubdirectory(@"Writer");
                papka.CreateSubdirectory(@"Incorrect");
            }
            catch (IOException e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }
            //Путь к файлу
            string path = @"C:\Users\a.filatov\Desktop\1\COMMA.txt";

            //Читаем текст в файле построчно
            string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);

            //Объявляем интервал времени
            TimeSpan intervaltimesum = new TimeSpan();

            //Текущее время в элементе массива
            TimeSpan current_time;

            //Счётчик
            int countTime = 0;

            //Создание потока для записи в файл
            StreamWriter W = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\a.filatov\Desktop\Test\Writer\Write.txt");
            StreamWriter A = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\a.filatov\Desktop\Test\Incorrect\Incorrect.txt");

            Int32[] arrCounter = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            //Цикл для считывания строк
            for (int i = 19; i < 1019; i++)
            {   
                //Установка разделителем массива запятой
                string[] elements = readText[i].Split(',');

                switch (elements[1])
                {
                    case "01": arrCounter[0]++; break;
                    case "02": arrCounter[1]++; break;
                    case "03": arrCounter[2]++; break;
                    case "04": arrCounter[3]++; break;
                    case "05": arrCounter[4]++; break;
                    case "06": arrCounter[5]++; break;
                }

                //Если четветрый элемент в строке существует, то работаем с ним
                if (elements.GetLength(0) > 4)
                {
                    //Разбор 4 элемента массива
                    try
                    {
                        //Разделитель ":"
                        string[] times = elements[4].Split(':');
                        int hours = int.Parse(times[0]);
                        int minutes = int.Parse(times[1]);
                        int seconds = int.Parse(times[2]);
                        current_time = TimeSpan.FromHours(hours) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);

                       // Запись в файл
                        W.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}  \t\t Текущее время = {3} Общее время = {4}", i - 18, elements[0], elements[4], current_time, intervaltimesum);

                        //Вывод 4 элемента массива в файл более 2 часов
                        if (current_time.TotalHours > 2)
                        {
                            // в отдельный файл выведем значение более 2-х часов
                            A.WriteLine("{0}", current_time);
                        }
                        else
                        {  // если меньше двух часов - тогда суммируем
                            intervaltimesum += current_time;
                            countTime++;
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        throw;
                    } 
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("01: {0}; 02: {1}; 03: {2}; 04: {3}; 05: {4}; 06: {5}", arrCounter[0], arrCounter[1], arrCounter[2], arrCounter[3], arrCounter[4], arrCounter[5]));
            //Закрытие потока 
            A.Close();

            //Вывод среднего времени в нужном формате
            TimeSpan intervalAverage = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(intervaltimesum.TotalSeconds / countTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Среднее время = {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", intervalAverage);

            //Запись в файл времени 
            W.WriteLine("\n\n Всё время отклонения = {0} в секундах = {1}", intervaltimesum, intervaltimesum.TotalSeconds);

            //Запись среднего времени
             W.WriteLine(" Среднее время {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", intervalAverage);
            W.Close();


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Подправил под Ваши требования.

Comment: Спасибо заработало......

Comment: Человеческое спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!