# Работа с файлом

Tags: c#

Дан текстовый файл с 1000 строками, который считывается построчно и разбивается запятыми,и записывается в массив, пример строк в нём.

```
001,03,043,04/07/15 16:02,00:00:25,00,00,00,Indexer #1 shot pin state is unknown
002,02,030,09/24/15 16:39, 00:00:04,00,00,01,ATT unable to detect tray at Gripper
```

Если в нём во втором элементе, я подсчитывал с помощью конструкции `switch case` количество `01,02,03,04,05,06` узлов, а как подсчитать в третей позиции количество тех или иных ошибок если номера их варьируются от одного до ста?

Comment: т.е. Вы хотите получить сколько раз у вас встречается 043, 030?

Comment: возьмите решение без switch [вашего предыдушего вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455278/177221) - ему все равно, какую колонку считать

Comment: Нет это пример только двух строк а их тысяча, и номера от 01 до 100.

Comment: Даю подсказку: там надо изменить **[1]** на любой другой индекс и будет возвращено количество таких значений

Comment: А если нам не известны коды ошибок?

Comment: Подсказчик ё моё

Comment: добавил коментарии [сюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455278/179270) попробуйте посмотреть, может счас Вам станет понятно.

Comment: как Вы не поймете этому коду без разницы какие там коды будут хоть 5968, он вернет количество повторений. а тот вариант который Вы там ответили как решение ущербен в этом плане, как только во Второй позиции добавится новое значение например 07, Вам придется дорабатывать Ваш switch, но как говорится дело Ваше

Comment: Да спасибо, я понял что вариант ущербен! Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете использовать `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (string item in myArray)
{
  string[] elements = item.Split(',');
  if (dictionary.ContainsKey(elements[2]))
  {
    dictionary[elements[2]] ++;
  }
  else
  {
    dictionary.Add(elements[2], 1);
  }
}
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,int> dict in dictionary)
{
  Console.Write("В тексте {0} ошибок типа {1}",dict.Value, dict.Key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt");    

var counter = new DictionaryCounter<string>();
var list = lines.Select(x => x.Split(',')[1]).ToList();
list.ForEach(counter.Increment);

counter.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("error={0}\tcount={1}", x.Key, x.Value));
```

Описываем класс `DictionaryCounter`:

```
public class DictionaryCounter<T> : Dictionary<T, int>
{
    public void Increment(T key)
    {
        Increment(key, 1);
    }
    public void Increment(T key, int incValue)
    {
        if (ContainsKey(key))
            this[key]++;
        else
            Add(key, incValue);
    }
    public void ForEach(Action<KeyValuePair<T, int>> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in this) { action(item); }
    }
}
```